# Package dependency when dependency not on nuget yet

Tags: xamarin, nuget

I have a Xamarin binding, and another one which depends on the first. In the second binding the dependency to the first requires the dependency to be published on nuget. However, as both are updated together, it's not possible to build the second binding without publishing the first.

Ideally what I'd like to do is depend on the first package locally when building, but in the package `.nuspec` depend on the nuget package. As the first package will be published first, when the second package is published the dependency can be satisfied. Is this possible?

Comment: I don't understand your workflow, maybe I haven't fully worken up yet, but NuGet will detect project references and automatically make them nuget dependencies. So, you shouldn't have to mess around with nuspec dependencies. let the tooling do it for you.

Comment: So it does! No package dependency required in the second binding.

Comment: @Nick, **In the second binding the dependency to the first requires the dependency to be published on nuget.** I am not sure what does it means, so can you give one example here?

Comment: @CherryBu-MSFT Before zivkan pointed out that VS creates the package dependency for you in the output package if your project references another package project, I thought you needed an explicit dependency on a package which would therefore need to be published on nuget. cheesebaron pointed out you could use a local package repo for this, but actually it isn't required at all.

Answer (score 0):

Do they need to live apart? Couldn't you have both projects live in the same solution? This way you could build them together, then package these two libraries separately afterwards.

Alternatively, you could create a local repository, which is just a folder where you put in your dependencies, and you can simply point to that folder as a NuGet repository. You can configure that through VS, or you can create a NuGet.config in the root of the repository and add an entry looking something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <packageSources>
        <add key="Local Packages" value="path/on/disk" />
    </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

This should automatically be picked up by NuGet and it will try to restore packages from here too.

Comment: I am packaging as part of the release build. I can have the projects in the same solution with a Reference to the first binding, but as the package reference still cannot be resolved it doesn't get added to the nuspec in the package. I'll try the local repo idea

Comment: As in the comment on my question by @zivkan, I do not need the package dependency. Simply having the reference to the other binding in the same solution is enough to generate the required package dependency in the second binding. So the local repo idea is not required (although that also worked)